# jquery selector and ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

i need a menu plugin of some sort that displays items in a horizontal list with only 5 items of the list shown but it should be scrollable by buttons on either side of the menu- and scrolling brings the next item into view and the first one out of view.

Only thing is, what could i use on an ipad web app, how does jquery operate on the ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is pure JavaScript so it will work fine on iPad, iPhone etc. too as long as the user does not disable JavaScript.

So you can use any jQuery menu plugins.
Here are some listings:

- http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-menu-plugins - list of 10 menu plugins
- http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins?type=44 - jQuery menu plugin list